# Adding coordinates that start with 0 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have a list of coordinates of archaeological sites I'm working on in the south of Israel and Sinai. The points were taken in the old Israeli system (Palestine 1923 Israel CS grid) in which some of the points start with 0's. When I try to add the table from excel or create a new one in ArcMap it automatically deletes the 0's so the points aren't accurate. The only option I've found to keep the 0's at the beginning is if the field is marked as a text field, in which case it won't allow me to add the points as coordinates.

How can I add coordinates that start with 0?

Comment: try adding them as text in Excel, then save your worksheet as a CSV or tab delimited text file. Open the text file in notepad and find and replace all " marks, save file then open in Arc

Comment: Sorry just tried this - it preserves the zeros but then Arc ignores them on import!

Comment: Essentially you are dealing with non-numeric system, some sort of grid based coordinate reference often used in army. You need to find converter

Comment: Can you enter them with a false number instead of the 0, and then after you have the points select them and use the Editor-Move to shift them back to their correct location?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of your points?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS Desktop coordinates cannot start with a zero.

Consequently, you will need to keep "shadow" text fields that enable you to also store copies of your coordinates in "left zero-filled" fields.